# Can I copy the files in my original /opt directory after I mount a new LVM on the /opt?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have new LVM on my Linux server and  I want to mount on my `/opt`. I have files in the `/opt` directory and I know after I mount, the files will be hidden. Is it possible to `rsync` the files in the `/opt` to the new mounted LVM? Is there a better way of going about this?

After I mounted the new LVM, I was not able to copy the files in the original `/opt` directory. I got the error: `no files to copy`.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you can use is:

1. mount the new LV to other mountpoint like `/opt_new`
2. do the sync between original `/opt` and `/opt_new`
3. check if the files are the same
4. unmount `/opt_new`
5. purge the files from /opt
6. mount new LV to `/opt`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Linux-based system so you can use a "bind mount" to access the now-hidden directory:

```
mount ... /opt                # Assume /opt is the new LV

mkdir -p /mnt/opt             # Temporary mountpoint
mount --bind /opt /mnt/opt    # Bind original /opt onto /mnt/opt
cp -a /mnt/opt/ /opt          # Copy file tree
umount /mnt/opt               # Done
```

As always, test the solution before applying it in a production environment